# PHP Multidimensional array find maximum of duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that I wish to find the maximum value of a key=>value, but only of duplicate specific keys and create a new key=>value with that maximum.

It's easier to explain by showing the initial array and the expected result

```
$data = array(
 0 => array('id' => '1a','info'=>'abc','level'=>1),
 1 => array('id' => '1a','info'=>'xyz','level'=>3),
 2 => array('id' => '2b','info'=>'uvw','level'=>2),
 3 => array('id' => '3c','info'=>'str','level'=>1),
 4 => array('id' => '3c','info'=>'str2','level'=>2),
 5 => array('id' => '4d','info'=>'uvw1','level'=>1),
);



$result = array(
  0 => array('id' => '1a','info'=>'abc','level'=>1,'max_level'=>3),
  1 => array('id' => '1a','info'=>'xyz','level'=>3,'max_level'=>3),
  2 => array('id' => '2b','info'=>'uvw','level'=>2,'max_level'=>2),
  3 => array('id' => '3c','info'=>'str','level'=>1,'max_level'=>2),
  4 => array('id' => '3c','info'=>'str2','level'=>2,'max_level'=>2),
  5 => array('id' => '4d','info'=>'uvw1','level'=>1,'max_level'=>1),
);
```

I've looked into finding the duplicate 'id' and the max'level' values but I've not been able to combine the two together and keep the non-duplicates.

Comment: So, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `array_walk` and `max` functions:

```
array_walk($data, function($v) use(&$max_levels){ $max_levels[$v['id']][] = $v['level']; });
foreach ($data as &$v) {
    $v['max_level'] = max($max_levels[$v['id']]);    
}

print_r($data);
```

https://eval.in/588966

Comment: Thank you! It was the array_walk bit I was getting stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

So, your task is split in two parts:

```
// first - find maximum level of every `id`
$max_values = array();
foreach ($data as $v) {
    if (!isset($max_values[$v['id']]) || $max_values[$v['id']] < $v['level']) {
        $max_values[$v['id']] = $v['level'];
    }
}

// second - add this level to $data
foreach ($data as &$v) {
    $v['max_level'] = $max_values[$v['id']];
}
```